# How to break down sets in Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on proving that 2 sets are equal. I feel confident that I can do this, but I am having difficulty with one part which is keeping me from proceeding to solve the problem.

I have $x \in C$ and ( $x \not\in (A-B)$ or $x \not\in (B-A)$)

I'm not exactly sure how to break this down further.

I have come up with:

$x \in C$ and ($x \not\in A$ and $x \in B$ or $x \not\in B$ and $x \in A$)

Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that : $$x \not \in (A-B) \iff x \notin  A \quad  \text{or} \quad  x \in B$$ so the statement : $$x \notin (A-B)  \quad  \text{or} \quad x \notin (B-A) $$ is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first consider the statement $x \not\in (A-B)$. Note that $A-B = A \cap B^c$. So, the statment $x\not\in (A-B)$ is the same as $x \not\in (A \cap B^c)$ is the same as $x \in (A \cap B^c)^c$ is the same as $x \in (A^c \cup B)$ (the last piece by D'Morgan). From here we see 
$$x \not\in (A-B) \iff \{(x \in A^c)\text{ or }(x \in B)\}$$ 
By interchanging the roles of $A$ and $B$, we will arrive at
$$
\{[x \not\in (A-B)] \text{ or }[x\not\in(B-A)]\} \iff \{[(x\in A^c)\text{ or }(x\in B)]\text{ or }[(x\in B^c)\text{ or }(x \in A)]\}
$$
But now, every element is in $A$ or $A^c$ (similarly $B$ or $B^c$), so by transitivity of "or" you see that, in fact,
$$
(x \in C) \text{ and } \underbrace{[(x \not\in (A-B))\text{ or }(x \not\in (B-A)]}_{\text{ true for every } x} \iff x\in C
$$